# addEventListener's binding behavior

Tags: javascript

Why does `addEventListener` change context to functions without context but not functions with binded context? Is there a rule of priority, or precedence?

Taking the following example:

```
function listenerA(e) {
  console.log(e.type, this);
}
function listenerB(e) {
  console.log(e.type, this);
}

target.addEventListener('click', listenerA); // click DOM Element
target.addEventListener('click', listenerB.bind(listenerB)); // click function (){}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6up68xLw/

I wonder why I get different `this` since both are functions run as callback for `addEventListener` and I would expect the same behaviour, which is either create new context for both, or keep the current (even if undefined).

Comment: In a basic sense, `f.bind(foo)` is the same as `bind(f, foo)` where `function bind(f, ctx) {return function () {return f.apply(ctx, arguments);};}`. This means `.bind` will always override the `this` value. Read more on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the
>   same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as
>   the function it is being called on (the bound function's target
>   function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(),
>   **which cannot be overridden**.

Comment: " which cannot be overridden." - ok, that was the answer. Missed that on MDN. Thank you. Just tested it and it is so. (https://jsfiddle.net/6up68xLw/1/). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`listenerB.bind(listenerB)` returns a new function. `addEventListener` changes both callbacks' context, which is the new function with the inner function remain untouched.

A possible implementation might be:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(context){
    var self = this;
    return function(){
        self.apply(context, arguments);
    };
};
```

Hope this helps you in understanding the behavior. `.bind` isn't some magic functions.